# how can i monitor bandwidth usage with playwright?

Tags: python, proxy, playwright

I'd like to be able to track the bandwidth usage for each playwright browser because I am using proxies and want to make sure I'm not using too much data.

I've tried stuff like

```
page.on("requestfinished", lambda request: bandwidth.append(request.sizes()["requestBodySize"] * 0.000001))
page.on("response", lambda response: bandwidth.append(len(response.body()) * 0.000001))
page.on('requestfailed', lambda requestfailed: proxy_logger.warning(f"{proxyInfo} Request Failed {requestfailed}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following code to get the traffic usage

```
res = await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/python/docs/network')

await res.request.sizes()



>>{'requestBodySize': 0, 'requestHeadersSize': 681, 'responseBodySize': 2876, 'responseHeadersSize': 666}
```